# POP3 server и base64 кодировка

Tags: c#, кодировка, pop3

Всем привет. Пытаюсь получить сообщения через POP3. Если подключиться через телнет к POP серверу и получить письмо, то само письмо приходит в base64 кодировке

```
Return-path: <or_die>
Received: from mail by f56.mail.ru with local
        id 1QkH5i-00016D-00
        for or_die; Fri, 22 Jul 2011 18:52:38 +0400
Received: from [myip] by e.mail.ru with HTTP;
        Fri, 22 Jul 2011 18:52:38 +0400
From: or_die
To: or_die
Subject: sdfsdf
Mime-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: mPOP Web-Mail 2.19
X-Originating-IP: [myip]
Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2011 18:52:38 +0400
Reply-To: Or_die <or_die@sssdsd.ru>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="--ALT--maaC0aLK1311346358"
Message-Id: <e1qkh5i-00016d-00.or_die@f56.mail.ru>
X-Spam: Not detected
X-Mras: Ok

----ALT--maaC0aLK1311346358
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UGFzc3dvcmQ6IDExMTEx
----ALT--maaC0aLK1311346358
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

CjxIVE1MPjxCT0RZPlBhc3N3b3JkOiAxMTExMTwvQk9EWT48L0hUTUw+Cg==
----ALT--maaC0aLK1311346358--

.
```

На ум только приходит обработка регулярным выражением, и то, что вырезалось, декодить из base64.
Может, есть другие варианты? Или покажите, как правильно, точнее грамотно всё это сделать. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> обработка регулярным выражением

Вы это серьёзно?? Зачем? Почему нельзя просто взять текст и декодировать его? Зачему тут regexp?

Чтобы раскрыть BASE64 используйте [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). На выходе вы поллучите байты. Чтобы из байтов получить текст (если это текст), используйте что-то вроде такого

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Только выберите кодировку из заголовков письма

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее и грамотней, взять готовую, отличную опенсорсную библиотечку
[OpenPOP.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/)
Там все предельно просто, в комплекте есть пример с исходниками.

Comment: Видимо человеку надо реализовать это самому. Наверное, задание какое-то или любопытство.

Comment: Любопытство конечно же, библиотеку уже давно нашел :)

Comment: Кстати, не всегда правильнее и грамотнее брать готовые библиотеки. Обычно эти готовые опенсорсные библиотеки - такое Г что нет слов.

Comment: Вот почему я и спрашивал :)

Comment: Правда если у вас нет нужных скилов, то вероятно вы напишете ещё одно ;)

Comment: В данном случае библиотечка добротная.

Comment: Пожалуй, соглашусь. При первых трёх минутх просмотра не вызывает отвращения, что несомненно добрый знак.